# Quartz2D and gradient line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, quartz-graphics

how can i draw gradient line with quartz2d?

Answer (score 3):

`CGContextDrawLinearGradient` draws gradients.  Use `CGContextClipToRect` (or related clipping functions) to clip to the region you want to fill with a gradient.

There's no support for stroking or filling a path with a gradient, you instead clip to the region you want to fill.

Answer (score 1):

I used this inside `drawRect:` and worked like a charm:

```
double slope, cosy, siny;
double halfWidth = 2; // the thickness of the line will be 2*halfWith

// the start and end points have to be inside UIView frame coordinates
CGPoint start = CGPointMake(30, 20);
CGPoint end = CGPointMake(80, 90);  

slope = atan2((start.y - end.y), (start.x - end.x));
cosy = cos(slope);
siny = sin(slope);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGGradientRef myGradient;
CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace;
size_t num_locations = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
CGFloat components[8] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  // Start color (White)
                          1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 }; // End color (Red)

myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, start.x -halfWidth*siny , start.y +halfWidth*cosy);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, end.x -halfWidth*siny , end.y +halfWidth*cosy  );
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, end.x +halfWidth*siny , end.y -halfWidth*cosy );
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, start.x +halfWidth*siny, start.y -halfWidth*cosy);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, start.x -halfWidth*siny , start.y +halfWidth*cosy);    
CGContextClip(context);

CGContextDrawLinearGradient (context, myGradient, start, end, 0);
CGColorSpaceRelease( myColorspace );
CGGradientRelease (myGradient);
```